# Where to make configuration changes to MySQL in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: server, mysql

I have a couple of Ubuntu 20.04 servers running on AWS, using MySQL 5.7 rather than 8.0.

When I set up the server I did some modifications to /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and everything worked fine. This is what I did previously in 16.04.

But it seems that a subsequent update via apt overwrote my changes on both servers. What is the proper way to do this in 20.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard practice for MySQL configuration settings is to create a separate file in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`. MySQL will read all `.cnf` files in that directory alphabetically, so if there are settings you need to configure that may also exist in the default configuration files, you’ll need to give them a file name starting with letter `n` or “higher”.

Generally what I do with MySQL configurations is keep some defaults in a Git repository that I then copy to a new server as needed. Here are some examples:

| File | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| `z-replication.cnf` | Contains template to set up replication |
| `z-highmemory.cnf` | Contains template configured for machines with more than 64GB RAM |
| `z-pi.cnf` | Contains template for very low-powered, write-based devices (like Raspberry Pis used for sensors) |

… and so on. By doing this, updates to MySQL do not interfere with my settings and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you.  It's the order in which the files were read that I was missing.  This seems to be working very well now.